# Crystal Reports: Changing a date group sort order using a parameter

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports 2008.

I would like to be able to use a parameter to prompt a user how he/she would like a date group grouped.
In other words...I have an order date that is currently grouped 'for each month'. I would like to give the user the option to select how they want the date group to be grouped using a parameter, (for each day, for each week, or for each month).
does anyone know how to do this?

Best regards to all.

Roger

Answer (score 0):

depending on the viewer your users are using, there are some options.
Our users use a program called DataLink Viewer by Millet Software, and there is a great way of creating "Click to Sort" reports. Please take a look [here](http://www.milletsoftware.com/Download/DataLink_Viewer_User_Manual.pdf) and look for the click-to-sort ability starting on page 65. 
For other Viewers, you could create a parameter for the sort. Then create a formula that looks something like 
If {SortParameter} = "Year" then (Year{mytable.datefield})
else if {SortParameter} = "Month" then (Month{mytable.datefield}) etc.
Then you will have to make the formula your group and sort by it.
You could also create another formula that will dynamically create a label for the Group Header to show "Year" or "Month" or "Day".

Hope that helps,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of video demos of click to sort and group swap expert in DataLink Viewer:
[Group Swap Expert](http://www.milletsoftware.com/Download/DLV_Group_Swap_Expert/DLV_Group_Swap_Expert.html)
[Click to change View/Groups](http://www.milletsoftware.com/Download/DLV_Demo_Click_to_Change_Formula/DLV_Demo_Click_to_Change_Formula.html)